# How do I get my JavaScript counter to show?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have this great JavaScript counter that works perfect. The only issue is that the actual information doesn't show up until the button is clicked first. But I want the counter & other text to constantly display and update as the buttons are being clicked.

What am I missing here?

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + localStorage.clickcount + " <br>Subscribers So Far! And...<br>" + (1500 - +localStorage.clickcount) + "<br>Subscribers To Go" ;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" id="paypal-btn1" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" id="paypal-btn2" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" id="paypal-btn3" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. Create another function to display the information then call it when the page load. Then call this function again when the counter increment when clicked the button.

```
<script>
    displayInformation(); 
    function displayInformation() {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + localStorage.clickcount + " <br>Subscribers So Far! And...<br>" + (1500 - +localStorage.clickcount) + "<br>Subscribers To Go" ;
    }
    function clickCounter() {
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.clickcount) {
                localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
            } else {
                localStorage.clickcount = 1;
            }
        displayInformation();/*Call this to refresh the click information*/
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        }
    }
</script>
```

See here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cepdawhm/)

Answer (score 0):

Add clickCounter() under your function so it will be executed on load.

Comment: @T.Doe - the answer doesn't really need sample code, because it already tells you exactly what to do. (Note that the `<script>` would need to appear after the elements it manipulates, e.g., just before the closing `</body>` tag.)

Comment: Wasn't me! I take all the help I can get, gratefully. Thank you @spa900

Comment: @spa900 Click will increment even if they didn't click the button once the page load.

Comment: Your first fiddle does increment the counter every time you load the page. The second fiddle doesn't work at all.